# MethodInfo.Invoke vs Type.InvokeMember?

Tags: .net, system.reflection, methodinfo, invokemember

What is the difference between the `MethodInfo.Invoke()` and `Type.InvokeMember()` methods?

Which should be used in which scenarios?

Which is the preferred way to invoke a method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending upon how you use it, `MethodInfo.Invoke` could be faster.  When you call `Type.InvokeMember` under the covers a `MethodInfo` is retrieved and then invoked.  Retrieving a `MethodInfo` is expensive.  If you are calling the same method multiple times, saving the `MethodInfo` in a variable and invoking it from the variable with save time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess both should be the same as far as invoking a Method or constructor is concerted but InvokeMember must be used if you want to get/set a field/property.

Check the links here for more details.

see [MethodBase.Invoke Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx)

see [Type.InvokeMember Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe(v=vs.110).aspx)